# Creating Evernote plugin that formats text

Tags: plugins, evernote

I would like to create an Evernote plugin that actually runs inside the Evernote application. Let's say on desktop only. Is it possible? Eventually I want to create a plugin that highlights syntax of code snippets inside a note. From looking on the API documentation I couldn't understand whether something like that is, even theoretically, possible. If it isn't possible, are there any other ways the task can be approached? Writing technical notes in Evernote annoys me greatly :)

Comment: Do you want to do display-time-only syntax highlighting? Or do you want to actually update the note's contents to include new coloring of the text? What platform are you on?

Comment: I use Evernote on multiple platforms, but mostly on MacOS. Both persistent and display-time-only approaches will suffice. I guess, I'll choose the easier one.

Comment: I have a similar desire to write a plugin that allows for easy reformatting of alphanumeric sequences into math and/or logic symbols. The majority of the Evernote development documentation seems to focus on their cloud services. Can anyone point me to some good resources?